# Как парсить объект типа Map из csv?

Tags: java, csv

Я работаю над записью и чтением классов в CSV-файл.
Один из классов имеет поле Map.
*(Я пытаюсь ввести в заказ значения блюд, которые заказал клиент)*

```
public class Order {
...
  private long id;
  private double totalCost;
  private Map<FoodItem, Long> menu;
...
}
```

Cейчас мой конвертер CSV to / from выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class OrderConverterCSV implements Converter<Order> {

    @Override
    public String[] toCsv(Order order) {
        return new String[]{
                String.valueOf(order.getId()),
                String.valueOf(order.getTotalCost()),
                String.valueOf(order.getMenu())
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Order fromCsv(String[] csvData) {
        return new Order(
                Long.parseLong(csvData[0]),
                Double.parseDouble(csvData[4]),
                Map.(csvData[5])//???
        );
    }
```

---

- Как правильно парсить это поле?
- Как я могу позже указать, какое значение блюда сохранить при сохранении в CSV?
- И наконец, может быть, я зря использую Map и должен использовать список или массив?

---

Comment: Нужно создать мап и при парсинге вставлять в нее значения. Ну а сам инстанс этой мапы использовать в конструкторе вашего заказа

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Order fromCsv(String[] csvData) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    // заполняем map
    // map.put(someKey, csvData[5]);

    return new Order(
            Long.parseLong(csvData[0]),
            Double.parseDouble(csvData[4]),
            map
    );
}
```

Comment: Но разве в строке с map не должно быть (csvData[5]), чтобы мы понимали, какую мы именно строку парсим?

Comment: мапа уже должна быть готова, т.е. заполняем ее раньше (добавил строки в ответ)

Comment: ведь проблема в том, что там не строка, а экземпляр класса (FoodItem). И я не могу его распарсить...возможно, в csv стоит хранить массив id?

Comment: Покажите пример файла, какой должен быть результат?